# Tool to convert Maven pom.xml to leiningen project.clj

Tags: maven, clojure, dependencies, leiningen

I want to use the leiningen `checkouts/` directory feature, but this feature requires that the project under `checkouts/` checked out directory contains a `project.clj`. I have a project (pallet) that has a `pom.xml` file but no `project.clj` file.

The data encoded in both project files is similar (name, version, description, dependencies, repositories) and I'm wondering if anyone knows of an existing tool to convert a Maven `pom.xml` to a leiningen `project.clj` file.

Comment: does #clojure on irc count as a tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some code written by Tom Hickey especially for this purpose - https://gist.github.com/1990327

Answer (score 1):

There is a Leiningen plugin [lein-nevam](https://github.com/thickey/lein-nevam), also by Tom Hickey, that converts Maven pom.xml files to project.clj files. -